# regular expression with 3 conditions with javascript and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to validate a certain element in xml by using regular expression.

```
<ConfigOption>value</ConfigOption>
```

Requirements for ConfigOption:

1. characters, numbers, underscore and space are allowed.
2. CONFIG-XX should be allowed. XX is numbers
3. CONFIGNAME?config=XX format should be allowed. xx is numbers.

Here is what I have.

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*$)|(?:\??config=\d)|(^CONFIG\-\d$)
```

for example:
'hello' should be ok.
'hello?config=20' should be ok
'CONFIG-20' should be ok.
'hello-' should fail
'hello*' should fail

can someone fix my regular expression? when I test 'hello=' or 'hello*' 'https://regex101.com/', it still matches.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I think matches your requirements. Let me know if it needs refining.

The real difference is in adding the lookahead `(?=\W)`.

Note the third condition is redundant and unneeded.

```js
const regex = /(?=\W)(^\b[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*(?:\??[Cc][Oo][Nn][Ff][Ii][Gg][=,-]\d{2}))/;
const tests = ['*HELLO', 'hello', 'hello=', 'hello*', 'hello?CONFIG-20', 'hello?CONFIG=20', 'config=20'];

for (const test of tests) {
  console.log(regex.test(test));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but '*HELLO' still matches. It shouldn't because of *.  And sorry that I edited the question to change one of the rules. it should be 'config=xx'. hello?config=20

Comment: I've edited it to only allow two digits and expect a word boundary to start.  I've answered the question as you asked it and then modified it. Please upvote/accept if helpful. Thanks.